# Trying to fill a List<Keypair<string,string>> with reflection is always empty

Tags: c#

With the following code, I am trying to create a List of KeyValuePair. However its always empty. Why?

During debug time you can see that the properties include the word Role on their name.  I also checked the type tblJob, and all those properties are string. See screenshot.

```
tblJob job = (tblJob)entity.Entity;

var listOfRolesnamesAndValues = 
    typeof(tblJob) //Get all properties that contains the Role name on it.
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public)
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Role") && p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(p.Name, p.GetValue(job, null) as string))
    .ToList();

   public partial class tblJob
    {
        public string ClientCode { get; set; }
        public string ClientName { get; set; }
        public string ClientURL { get; set; }
        public string JobCode { get; set; }
        public string JobName { get; set; }
        public string JobURL { get; set; }
        public string LongJobDescription { get; set; }
        public string iPowerLink { get; set; }
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        public string ChargeType { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public string ProductGroup { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> GrossEstimatedFee { get; set; }
        public string LineOfService { get; set; }
        public string LineOfServiceCode { get; set; }
        public string LineOfServiceRole { get; set; }
        public string LineOfServiceRolePD { get; set; }
        public string LineOfServiceRoleMAPO { get; set; }
        public string LineOfServiceRoleMA { get; set; }
        public string LineOfServiceRoleSTAFF { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnitCode { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnitRole { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnitRolePD { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnitRoleMAPO { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnitRoleMA { get; set; }
        public string BusinessUnitRoleSTAFF { get; set; }
        public string OperatingUnit { get; set; }
        public string OperatingUnitCode { get; set; }
        public string OperatingUnitRole { get; set; }
        public string OperatingUnitRolePD { get; set; }
        public string OperatingUnitRoleMAPO { get; set; }
        public string OperatingUnitRoleMA { get; set; }
        public string OperatingUnitRoleSTAFF { get; set; }
        public int Terminated { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TerminatedDate { get; set; }
        public string JobPartner { get; set; }
        public string JobManager { get; set; }
        public string JobDirector { get; set; }
        public string BillPartner { get; set; }
        public string BillManager { get; set; }
        public string JobTeam { get; set; }
        public string JobEntity { get; set; }
        public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        public string BillContact { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Confidential { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Try to add BindingFlags.Instance to the binding flags filter: BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, it sounds odd to at any time to operate on a List of KeyValuePairs. A list of KeyValuePairs should be a dictionary.

Comment: note to vc's suggestion: Exactly. When scannig via reflection, you very often **must pass** one of `Instance,Static` and `Public,NonPublic`. If you miss any of them, you will get empty result set.

Comment: @JosteinKjønigsen: no, it is not. The Tuple class is not always available, anontypes cause problems when trying to expose them as return values, and the ToDictionary would throw if the key occurs many times. KeyValuePair is often the first thing guaranteed to be able to hold two-value tuple. In this precise example, ToDictionary or Dictionary would surely throw, as a NAME has many ROLES assigned.

Comment: @vc74 post it as an answer, that worked so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @LuisValencia There you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `BindingFlags.Instance` to the binding flags filter: `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance`.

More on binding flags can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx).